# How to get all connected apps and devices from google fit?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am working on an app which reads data from Google Fit. As there could be many apps writing to Google Fit, there are high chances of duplicated data written to Google Fit.

To avoid duplicate date, my app allow user to choose a single app from all connected apps and devices from Google Fit. So far, I did not find any API which list all connected apps and devices with Google Fit. There is an API DataSourceResult.getDataSources(), but this API is not returning anything.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out?

Comment: No, so far there is no way to get it